# VBA delay and freeze while updating data

Tags: excel, vba, api, excel-addins

I have three data sets in two separate sheets

1. sheet("Price History")
2. sheet("Model")
3. sheet("Master")

Both ("Price History" and "Model") are pulling data from add-ins / API directly.

I have created a loop to draw all the tickers, and it will update in the "Pirce History", then it will update each time for each loop, but since it takes some time for the API to update the ticker, it can only show the results last ticker in the whole array.

I tried to create a wait function with do event, but the "Price History" doesn't update at all, and have tried to implement 'Application.Wait(Time). Price History did not update in both circumstances.

```
Public Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
        nSec = nSec + Timer
        While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
        Wend
        End Sub



Sub Macro1()

    'Variables
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim des As Worksheet
    Dim symbols() As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Variant
    Dim lastSymbolsRow As Long
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim rowcount As Integer
    Dim answer As Integer
    
    'Initial value of worksheet
    Set sws = Sheets("Master")
    Set des = Sheets("Model")
    
    'Calculate the last row and capture value into array
    lastSymbolsRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    symbols = sws.Range("A1:A" & lastSymbolsRow).Value2
    rowcount = 0
    
    'Start to populate ticker into array
    For Each i In symbols
      
        'update variable into sheets(model) in formula
        des.Range("B1") = i
        wait (60)
                
        'copy updated results from recalculation from different ticker
        des.Range("A50:H50").Copy
    
        'paste value to the master sheet
         If rowcount = 0 Then
            Sheets("Master").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            Else
            Sheets("Master").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
         End If
            
         rowcount = rowcount + 1
        'End if
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: `in two separate sheets` you list 3 sheets right after. `If rowcount = 0 Then....rowcount = rowcount + 1` this will only trigger/paste once. Also, if set ranges to each other instead of copy/paste, it will be much faster (aka less wait).